# How to resolve the messy code after transform the jsp to java code

Tags: java, jsp

In jsp, it has <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=GBK" %>. There is some Chinese in jsp. But after transform the jsp to java code, the Chinese has changed to Messy code.

```
out.print("<TR><TD align='right'>缂佸牏顏粩顖氬經閸欙拷</TD><TD><INPUT type=text name=p1 size=10 value=3389></TD><TD><input type=submit value=\"瀵拷閸氼垳绮撶粩鐥�"></TD></TR>");
```

Is there any way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your charset and page encode into your tag.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

You must include in every page you want the same encoding.